# Can I use a plastic or fiberglass box to install a 14-50 outlet or is a metal box required?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

The title says it all.  If plastic or fiberglass is allowed by code, what if any cons would there be?

Comment: Is it for indoor or outdoor, is it flash mounted or box.

Comment: Answer to the title is check your local codes.

Comment: indoor.  I don't know what flash mounted is but it will go into a gyp wall so the outlet face is flush with the gyp, approx 8" from the breaker panel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same cons as any application of a plastic box .vs. steel - not as sturdy, not as good at containing arcs and preventing a fire. Sturdy may come into play quicker with a 14-50 since the plug/unplug forces are considerable.

Code is a minimum, and barring location in an area with stricter modifications, to USA NEC a listed box of adequate size is allowed, for the most part. Some areas (or occupancies) do not allow plastic, but if plastic is allowed it's not generally limited to a particular size of outlet (but the box has to have suitable entrances for the wire/cable/conduit being used. And it does have to be of adequate size for "box fill" based on number and size of wires, and devices connected to wires. That takes a big box for wires typical of a 50A circuit.)